# Recommended course of action if you see users attempting to game the rep system?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation, ethics

Just wondering what the recommended course of action is if you see a user attempting to game the reputation system? (In this instance, they were asking someone to hold off/remove an existing upvote because they were presumably rep-capped.)

Should any action be taken (if so, what - mark as spam, or add comment for moderator), or is it fine to leave this as-is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what they asked.  It's not 'gaming' the system.  Gaming the system would be to create accounts and then use those accounts to vote up your 'main' account (so called 'sock puppet' accounts).

The reason it's not gaming is because the other user is free to vote up or vote down for any reason, at any time.  In fact, other users are free to vote that user down because they asked someone to vote them up.  Still other users are free to vote that person up because others voted him down because he asked them to vote him up.

You get the idea.

Comment: More proof you should be in the elections for mod

Comment: +1 Thanks for the comments - my own thoughts were along the lines of "sad, yet strangely amusing", but I thought I'd check in case such things are taken more seriously.

Comment: The user in question also hit by going from ~50 to over 310 rep by getting a single upvote on every one of their questions/answers. Pretty obvious sock-puppet voting.

Comment: @Meager the Vote Fraud system will take care of that.  If it doesn't, feel free to flag the user's comment/question/answer and let the mods know why you're flagging, "User just got upvotes for every question/answer - suspect serial upvoting".

Comment: @meagar To be honest, I suspect the user in question will implode once they discover things like the rep-cap anyway, so I wouldn't lose sleep over it. :-)

Comment: @George @midda I'm not worried about it, I'm aware of [Vote Fraud and You](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/). I just thought it was worth mentioning in the context of "gaming the system"; there's more going on than simply "I've hit the rep cap! Hold your upvote for tomorrow plz"